# Using str_replace to translate a MySQL Table in html

Tags: php, mysql

---

I have a website which contains a pricelist of CS:GO items. Now, how I did is this:

```
MySQL DB w/ All prices --> SELECT FROM DB Where X ( Item name ) --> echo Table
```

( Works fine )

---

Now I want to do a translation of the item names. How I planned to do it:

```
MySQL DB --> $result= From Where ( signature character ) --> $translate = str_replace (signature character from $result)
```

However, there's an issue with the code or str_replace I think.

$translate returns $result with no filtering.

```
        <?php
require 'lang.php';
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$dbname = "";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Filter Name
$sql = "SELECT Name, Price FROM utf WHERE Name LIKE 'K%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Translate
$tr = str_replace('K','Karambit','$result');

// Echo Translation ( Testing Purposes )
if (isset($tr)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$tr."</td><td>";

}

//Draw 

if ($tr->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class=\"CSSTableGenerator style=\"width:600px;height:150px;\"><table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th></tr></div>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $tr->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["Name"]."</td><td>".$row["Price"]." ".$row["Trend"]."</td></tr>";
    }
   echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

//Close 
$conn->close();
?>
```

---

Original code if that matters:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$dbname = "";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Name, Price FROM paid WHERE Name LIKE '%kar%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class=\"CSSTableGenerator style=\"width:600px;height:150px;\"><table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th></tr></div>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["Name"]."</td><td>".$row["Price"]." ".$row["Trend"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You are trying to translate the items name? or price?

Comment: `$result` isn't a string, you need to do the translate after you call `$result->fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: @FilipeFerreira The name

Comment: Just saw your answer. Marking ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL's `REPLACE()` function:

```
$sql = "SELECT REPLACE(Name, 'K', 'Karambit') AS Name, Price FROM utf WHERE Name LIKE 'K%'";
```

If you want to do it in PHP, you have to do it after fetching the row:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = str_replace('K', 'Karambit', $row['Name']);
    echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$row["Price"]." ".$row["Trend"]."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: One last question ! How do I fit the lang function into the equation? This didn't work: `$name = str_replace('K', 'lang['ka']);', $row['Name']);` 


This is the lang.php included in the file: `<?php
function lang($phrase){
    static $lang = array(
        'ba' => 'Bayonet',
        'ka' => 'Karambit'
    );
    return $lang[$phrase];
}
?>`

Comment: It should be `lang('ka')`. Square brackets are for array indexing, parentheses are for function arguments.